# Setting Sessions Using Rspec/ Rack::Test in Sinatra Tests

Tags: ruby, session, rspec, sinatra, capybara

I am trying to test a Sinatra application that is using oauth that has the following code being run before every route for the callback:

```
before do
  unless session.has_key?(:oauth_token) || request.path == '/auth/callback'
    access_url = oauth_client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: ENV['CALLBACK'])
    puts "Redirecting to #{access_url}"
    redirect "#{access_url}"
  end
end
```

For my tests, I simply just want to set the `session[:oauth_token]` to *anything* so that I get past this block and move onto the test. However, after hours of searches and experimentation, I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried `Rack::Test` to try and set it this way:

```
describe "Visit home page", js: true do
    before { get '/', {}, { 'rack.session' => { oauth_token: 'blahblahblah' } } }
    it "has a list of products" do
      get "/"
      expect(page).to have_link("Clear & Mild Foam Handwash Refill, Fragrance-Free, 1250mL Refill, 3/Carton")
      expect(page).to have_link("Coffee Portion Packs, 1.5oz Packs, Hazelnut Crème, 24/Carton")
    end
  end
end
```

and my `spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path '../../server.rb', __FILE__
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rack/test'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

set :environment, :test

Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

module RSpecMixin
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  def app() Sinatra::Application end

  def setup_session(session = {})
    Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash.stub(:new).and_return(session)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include RSpecMixin
end
```

What is the best way to go about actually setting a session before every route?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```rb
env 'rack.session', oauth_token: 'blahblahblah'
get '/'
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/rack/rack-test/blob/b667b83ce08335ab555a35e4ee95bb92b16af469/spec/rack/test_spec.rb#L375).

Comment: This didn't quite work. My tests was still getting redirected by the callback because it didn't recognize the session. When I loaded a `pry`, it looked like  it did set a `session` variable, but it didn't persist I guess.